# Invalid Connection String on .Net Teradata connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, teradata

I am trying to connect Teradata using .Net with the below code.

But when I execute it, it throws an error stating **Invalid connection string**
on

`TdDataAdapter adapter = new TdDataAdapter(cn.ConnectionString,cmd.CommandText);`

Here's the complete code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Teradata.Client.Provider;
using System.Data;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TdConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new TdConnectionStringBuilder();
        connectionStringBuilder.DataSource = "URK";
        connectionStringBuilder.Database = "DB";
        connectionStringBuilder.UserId = "USERNAME";
        connectionStringBuilder.Password = "PASSWORD";
        connectionStringBuilder.AuthenticationMechanism = "LDAP";

        TdConnection cn = new TdConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString;
        cn.Open();

        TdCommand cmd = new TdCommand("EXEC MACRONAME", cn);
        TdDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        TdDataAdapter adapter = new TdDataAdapter(cn.ConnectionString,cmd.CommandText);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);

        myLabel.Text= ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["event_id"].ToString();

        cmd.Dispose();
        cn.Close();
    }
}
```

I tried using `connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString` instead of the one used above but I still got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just swap parameters

```
TdDataAdapter adapter = new TdDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, cn.ConnectionString);
```

according to signature of `TdDataAdapter` constructor

```
public TdDataAdapter( 
   string commandText,
   string connectionString
)
```

See [docs](https://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/tdnetdp/15.11/help/Teradata.Client.Provider~Teradata.Client.Provider.TdDataAdapter~_ctor(String,String).html)

Comment: Yep, you're correct !. Strangely Visual Studio suggests opposite in intellisense

Comment: https://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/tdnetdp/15.11/help/Teradata.Client.Provider~Teradata.Client.Provider.TdDataAdapter.html 

Here it suggests opposite as well. See example